# Connect-AzureAD blank page on Single Sign-in

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to connect to AzureAD through PowerShell using the command `Connect-AzureAD`, but I'm getting a blank page on Single Sign-on.

[image]

However, it works like a charm when I use the command `Connect-MsolService`.

[image]

I've already tried troubleshooting, like suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-sso), but I don't think it is a issue related to my MFA provider as it works when I open in a web browser.

Comment: Can you try using a personal phone's hotspot connection ? Some users reported this happens due to some firewall restrictions

Comment: Not really. I have upvoted your answer cuz it's helpful, I couldn't solve this issue though. Another person is looking into it now, I hope they can figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 Win32 clients (Outlook, Word, Excel, and others) with versions 16.0.8730.xxxx and above are supported using a **non-interactive flow**. Other versions are not supported; on those versions, users will enter their usernames, but not passwords, to sign-in.

To troubleshoot single sign-on setup issues in Office 365, Intune, or Azure, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2530569/troubleshoot-single-sign-on-setup-issues-in-office-365-intune-or-azure).

Hope it helps you.